# EJB InjectionProviderException failed to inject an EJB

Tags: ejb, code-injection

i have an error when i tried to inject an EJB in a controller.

```
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.ScheduleController/calendrierDao,Remote 3.x interface =dao.CalendrierDao,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=dao.CalendrierDao,refType=Session into class controllers.
```

i dont know it is caused by the bean itself or..

```
    @EJB
private ActionDao actionDao;

@EJB
private CalendrierDao calendrierDao;
```

The first one is injected correctly and i can use it.
But the second one gives me the error aforementioned.

the code of the ejb that failed:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import entities.Action;
import entities.TCalendrier;
import entities.Titre;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class CalendrierDao implements ICalendrierDao, Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -270548339881483437L;
// private static final String SELECT_ALL_CALENDAR =
// "SELECT cal FROM t_calendriers cal where c.utilCreation =: utilCreation";
private static final String SELECT_TITLE_NAME = "SELECT t.titreEnClair FROM t_titres t  

private FacesMessage message;
private List<TCalendrier> allCalendar;

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "GA2010-ejbPU-dev")
private EntityManager em;

public CalendrierDao() {
    super();
}
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    String codeUser = (String) sess.getAttribute("codeUser");

    try {

        TypedQuery<TCalendrier> requete = em.createNamedQuery(
                "typeCalendrier.findAll", TCalendrier.class);

        // TypedQuery<TCalendrier> requete =
        // em.createQuery(SELECT_ALL_CALENDAR, TCalendrier.class);
        requete.setParameter("utilCreation", codeUser);
        allCalendar = requete.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        this.message = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

}

public List<TCalendrier> getAllCalendar() {

    return allCalendar;
}

public String getTitleName(Integer refTitre_p) {
    String titre = null;

    try {

        Query requete = em.createQuery(SELECT_TITLE_NAME);

        requete.setParameter("refTitre", refTitre_p);
        titre = (String) requete.getSingleResult();

    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        nre.printStackTrace();
    }

    return titre;

}
```

}

Comment: CalendrierDao is not an EJB, it's a JSF managed bean, so you won't be able to `@Inject` it

Comment: Does an EJB can be EJB and JSF managed bean at the same time or does it create conflicts?

Comment: An EJB and a JSF Managed Bean are by definition different things, though it is perfectly possible to use EJB's in the view using CDI. There are some very good  reasons to expose stateful EJB's to your JSF pages rather than JSF Managed Beans, simply by naming them through CDI. Better scope management, extended persistence context, improved transactional behavior and avoiding thread safety issues concerning the Http Session are just four of them, on top of the standard benefits of Stateful Session Beans. Check out Adam Bien's writings if you'd like to know more.